# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable in the Ipython console

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate cpmx, hmx, smpx, tmpx and smvx by doing simple interpolation after loading the data from excel into pandas dataframe.

While calling the function with `cpmx=absmatdata(1,0,0,0,44.011,100)` I see:

> 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Any idea how to go about this?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def absmatdata(a,b,c,d,material,tmp_ref):
    material_map = {2.016: 'H2', 28.016: 'N2', 32.000: 'O2', 32.065: 'S',
                18.016: 'H2O', 64.065: 'SO2', 12.001: 'C Graphite', 
                28.011: 'CO', 44.011: 'CO2', 16.043: 'CH4', 30.070: 'C2H6',
                44.097: 'C3H8', 58.124: 'C4H10'}
    if material in material_map:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name=material_map[material])        
    else:
        print('No data for this material available')    
        df = [list(np.arange(0,1100,100)),list(np.arange(0,11,1)),list(np.arange(0,11,1)),list(np.arange(0,11,1)),list(np.arange(0,11,1))]
    tmp = df.values[:,0]
    cpm = df.values[:,1]
    hm = df.values[:,2]
    smp = df.values[:,3]
    smv = df.values[:,4]
    tn = np.size(df)
    tmp0 = tmp_ref
    tmpx = a
    cpmx = 0
    hmx = b
    smpx = c
    smvx = d
    if a==0 and b==0 and c==0 and d==0:
        print('All values are zero')
    elif a!=0 and b==0 and c==0 and d==0:
        print('T interpolation')
        for i in range(0,tn-1):
            if tmpx > tmp(i) and tmpx <= tmp(i+1):
                int_fak = (tmpx-tmp(i))/(tmp(i+1)-tmp(i))
                cpmx = cpm(i) + int_fak*(cpm(i+1)-cpm(i))
                hmx = hm(i) + int_fak*(hm(i+1)-hm(i))
                smpx = smp(i) + int_fak*(smp(i+1)-smp(i))
                smvx = smv(i) + int_fak*(smv(i+1)-smv(i))
    return tmpx, cpmx, hmx, smpx, smvx
```

Comment: If you have a stacktrace, then include it in your question

Comment: Which line rise the error? Can you provide F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx ? Or atleast error message?

Comment: Maybe you re-use the name "absmatdata" ?

Comment: The error message is correctly describing the problem. You write expressions like `tmp(i)` which makes python believe you want to call a function `tmp` (which is a numpy array) with argument `i`. Since numpy arrays are not supposed to be called as a function the error occures. You have to use square brackets for indexing `[]`. this is Python, not MATLAB

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to edit my question to add stacktrace

Comment: @gehbiszumeis thanks mate, I am slowly getting used to python

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for your improvement, I appreciate it. The original quation has been solved now, So should I post a new question for the error I am getting right now ? what do you suggest ?

Comment: In theory, yes, post a new question. My tip though: make sure you did proper prior research. Such us: putting the "generic" parts of the error message into a search engine. When you start to learn something new, rest assured: most of the problems you will run into ... they have been asked and answered here before. It is one essential skill to find solutions yourself, first. And then, when you are really stuck for a good while, then you turn to others for help ;-)

Comment: Beyond that: thanks for the kind and thoughtful comeback! And dont forget to delete comments that are no longer needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You set df to DataFrame
- You set tmp = df.values[:,0]
- You have numpy.ndarry at tmp
- You have to get its items with `[]` not with `()`

Your loop part

```
 if tmpx > tmp(i) and tmpx <= tmp(i+1):
                 int_fak = (tmpx-tmp(i))/(tmp(i+1)-tmp(i))
                 cpmx = cpm(i) + int_fak*(cpm(i+1)-cpm(i))
                 hmx = hm(i) + int_fak*(hm(i+1)-hm(i))
                 smpx = smp(i) + int_fak*(smp(i+1)-smp(i))
                 smvx = smv(i) + int_fak*(smv(i+1)-smv(i))
```

Should change with

```
if tmpx > tmp[i] and tmpx <= tmp[i+1]:
                int_fak = (tmpx-tmp[i])/(tmp[i+1]-tmp[i])
                cpmx = cpm[i] + int_fak*(cpm[i+1]-cpm[i])
                hmx = hm[i] + int_fak*(hm[i+1]-hm(i))
                smpx = smp[i] + int_fak*(smp[i+1]-smp[i])
                smvx = smv[i] + int_fak*(smv[i+1]-smv[i])
```

Also you need to change your `tn` to

```
tn = np.size(df.values[:,0])
```

Comment: Thank you @Ihsan Cemil Cicek, I changes the round brackets to square brackets.The error has now gone. But now I have a new error "index 38 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 38" in the line "if tmpx > tmp[i] and tmpx <= tmp[i+1]:". Does it has anything to do with number of rows ? the excel file has 38 rows and 5 columns, it is an 38x5 array

Comment: index 38 is [37] actually you should start with [0] index.

Comment: which line you mean [0] ?

Comment: I could not able to find solution can you provide excel file?

Comment: Dropbox, Drive or something like that.

Comment: @Tudee92 Please dont do that. This community is "one question, one answer". You shouldnt use this as cheap debugging service. One part of learning programming is to work on issues yourself. Dont go "here is one more problem now" ping pong in comments. Instead: **accept** this helpful answer, and if you run into more issues, rather write up a new question!

Comment: @Tudee92 can you also upvote my answer if you fix your problesm :))